# cookies and sessions in php

Tags: php, cookies, mysqli

I've tried everything and nothing works, so, I've created a login page. Now when I log in first I get an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\wamp\www\ucp\index.php on line 39

and then when i login it wont at first change the page look:

[image]

Other images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/goCPX.jpg

and this is the whole code

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","samp");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to the database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

session_start();

if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    setcookie("login", '',time()-86400); # delete cookie
    exit(); # stop executing here
    header('index.php');
}


if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{

    $userName = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : null;
    $userPass = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : null;

    $hashedPass = hash('whirlpool', $userPass);
    $query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'";

    $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row)
    {
        $session = md5($userName.$hashedPass);
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Igraci SET session = '$session' WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'");
        setcookie("login", $session,time()+3600);
        echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["login"]). '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';

    }
    else
    {
        die('Account has not been found.');
    }
}

if(isset($_COOKIE["login"]) && mb_strlen(isset($_COOKIE["login"]) == '32'))
{
    $session = $con->real_escape_string($_COOKIE["login"]);
    $query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE session = '$session' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query); $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row['Ime']) 
    { 
        echo "User is already logged in with username ".$row['Ime']. " and hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["login"]). '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
        exit(); 
    }

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Roleplay Factory User Control Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome, please login to your account.</h1>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" placeholder = "Username" name="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder = "Password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form> 

<div class="footer">
<p>roleplay factory &copy; 2016 all rights reserved</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you tried to add `error_reporting(0);` to the top of the script ?

Comment: Is `$_COOKIE["login"]` set? It seems like an array index is pointing nowhere.

Comment: (Code prone to sql injection attacks.)

Comment: Well it is

        setcookie("login", $session,time()+3600);

Answer (score 1):

You created the cookie **after** the global variable $_COOKIE (which contains cookie information that PHP received with the HTTP request) was filled with data so you can't access it yet.

Check if the cookie exists. If not, it's first login and output just the value.

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ "login" ] ) ) {
  // your original line of code
  echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["login"]). '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
} else {
  echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($session). '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
}
```

Comment: Well when i check it like  

 echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["login"]). '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';

its not outputing value but when i put it like 

  echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($session). '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';

it does output session, and session is saved in db idk what is wrong :S

Comment: It means you're also incorrectly setting the cookie value on the line above. I used $session in my code since you're putting it as a value into the cookie.

Comment: Then how should i set the cookie, it is

setcookie("login", $session,time()+3600);

Sorry if im annoying but i've just started learning php

Comment: You just have a logic error in your code. You're setting the cookie value to `$session` (the MD5 hash) but you probably wanted `$userName` ... So just change `$session` to `$userName` in your `setCookie()` and in the echo for non-logged user (when `$_COOKIE['login']` is not set).

Comment: Thanks i got it figured out, but now i have other problem, when i log in, the Username input and Password input and submit code stays on the same page, and if i click submit again it will hide that You are logged in with hash: name but cookie stays

http://i.imgur.com/y6QEPW0.jpg

code:

http://pastebin.com/afefetS8

Answer (score 0):

Your line 39, as pointed out by the error message, looks like:

```
echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["login"]). '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
```

You don't check if `$_COOKIE["login"]` is set.